# How to read unicode characters from server socket

Tags: java, sockets, utf-8, server

I need to receive a unicode (UTF-8) string sent by client on a server side. The length of the string is of course unknown.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(567);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

I can read bytes using `in.read()` (until it returns -1) but the problem is that the string is unicode, in other words, every character is represented by two bytes. So converting the result of `read()` which would work with normal ascii characters makes no sense.

## update

As per suggestions bello, I created the reader as follows:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
```

I've changed the client side to send a newline (`#10#13`) after each string.
But the new problem is I get bullshit instead of real string if i call:

```
in.readLine();
```

And print the result I get some nonsense string (I cannot even copy it here) although I am not dealing with non-latin chars or anything else.

To see what's going on I introduced following code:

```
int j = 0
while (j < 255){
    j++;
   System.out.print(in.read()+", ");
}
```

So here I just print all bytes received. If I send "ab" I get:

```
97, 0, 98, 0, 10, 13,
```

This is what one would expect, but than why the readLine method doesn't produce "good" results?
Anyway, if we couldn't find the actual answer, I should probably collect the bytes (like above) and create my string from them? How to do that?

P.S. Just a quick note - I am on windows.

Answer (score 4):

Use `new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")` in order to set properly the name of the `charset` to use while reading the `InputStream` coming from your client

Answer (score 3):

When creating `InputStreamReader` you can set encoding like this:

```
BufferedReader in = 
     new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")
);
```

Comment: This solution seems valid, but I have some problem. I send a string terminated by \10\13 from the client and on the server side I do `System.out.println(in.readLine());` however, what I receive is compleet gibberish. The interesting thing is if I read data byte by byte it seems that everything is okay (e.g. AB is encoded like 65,0,66,0 or like that). Only the very first letter of my string is correct and all others are just unreadable.

Comment: On a client side instead of sending \10\13, try sending two chars: \u000D and \u000A .

Comment: The problem is that client is in C++ and I know very little about that language. Any way I'll try to find how to do so.

Comment: I updated the first post including some research about my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
    Reader in = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(
                    clientSocket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Note the [StandardCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) class. It is supported since Java 1.7 and provides more elegant way to specify a standard encoding like `UTF-8`.